# The code works perfectly fine in PyCharm but not in VS code

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I was trying to do basic OpenCV operation. The code worked fine in PyCharm with no errors. Got an output window. However, when in VS code I get the following erroe.

```
PS E:\Personal Project\OpenCV> python -u "e:\Personal Project\OpenCV\Codes\Start.py"
[ WARN:0@0.029] global loadsave.cpp:244 cv::findDecoder imread_('Capture.PNG'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Personal Project\OpenCV\Codes\Start.py", line 8, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Along with that Here is the code

```
import cv2

# Read the image
img = cv2.imread('Capture.PNG')

# Display the image
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My Python Version 3.10.7, Python3 Version 3.9.13
My Pip, pip3 version 22.3.1.
Both my VSCode and PyCharm interpreter uses python 3.10.7

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour]. you haven't googled/searched for this error message. when you do, you'll find hundreds of people that already had the exact same issue, and there's almost always a solution... the same solution for all of them.

Comment: Provide your file structure and what folder you open in vscode as workspace.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is in the line `img = cv2.imread('Capture.PNG')`

It seems that the directory "Capture.png" doesn't exist... so maybe recheck your directory and make sure you have the image saved correctly

Comment: But the image is in same folder. Its working for PyCharm though

Comment: maybe try using the full path instead of the relative path?

Comment: Because you're using a relative path, make sure the working directory is the same for both (use os.getcwd() to verify). Alternatively you can use an absolute path.

Comment: Hello, so yeah it works for full path. But I didn't need the full path for PyCharm but I needed it for VSCode. The path will change if I move the source code folder into another drive. In that case I have to manually change it. I was hoping for the code to work in a way that everything will be in same file and it will read it and work fine even if I change the folder from E drive to D drive, hope that clarifies

Comment: Read about what "working directory" is and check what's the working directory when starting your application from vscode. Probably you can choose/set it in the project settings.